# How to get temporary AWS credentials via Cognito Identity Pool

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am looking to get temporary AWS credentials through a Cognito Identity Pool to send data to a Kinesis stream through API Gateway. **One thing to note is that I am trying to do this without an AWS SDK because the language it will be written in eventually does not have a compatible SDK**. I am testing the solution in Python and seem to be missing something as I keep getting a 400 error. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here?

```
import requests

url = 'https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' #cognito regional endpoint

headers = {
    'X-AMZ-TARGET': 'com.amazonaws.cognito.identity.model.AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity',
    'X-AMZ-DATE': '20151020T232759Z'
}

body = {
    'IdentityId': 'us-east-1:123456789' #identity id
}

response = requests.post(url = url, data = body, headers = headers)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding a content type header, converting the single quotes in the body to double quotes, and wrapping the body dictionary in quotes as well.

```
import requests

url = 'https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' #cognito regional endpoint

headers = {
    "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    "X-AMZ-TARGET": "com.amazonaws.cognito.identity.model.AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity",
    "X-AMZ-DATE": "20151020T232759Z"
}

body = '''{
    "IdentityId": "123456789"
}'''

response = requests.post(url = url, data = body, headers = headers)
print(response.text)
```